# Is that any ways to install Package: Azure.Identity into Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I try to use the lowest version of Azure identity which is the version 1.0.0-preview.1 to install in Visual studio 2013 that can support by netframe 4.6.1, but its appear the error of

> Install-Package : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Version'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value for the argument, and then try running the command again.
> At line:1 char:47

Does anyone have a solution? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using nuget and change the version manually in the .csproj file

Comment: it can't I try to install netframe 4.8.1 into my visual studio and install the earliest version of azure identity that can be support it also come out the error of Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Version'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value for the argument, and then try running the command again.
At line:1 char:47
+ NuGet\Install-Pa